# Difference between two arrays? A - B = C

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to get the difference between two arrays value.

```
function get_customer_gain() {
    global $wpdb; 
    $users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SUM(wp_wpdatatable_1.bike) as sumed FROM wp_wpdatatable_1");
    foreach( $users as $user ) {
        echo $user->sumed;
    }
}
add_shortcode('customer_gain', 'get_customer_gain');
```

And my second query is

```
function get_customer_gain() {
    global $wpdb; 
    $users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SUM(wp_wpdatatable_1.car) as sumed FROM wp_wpdatatable_1");
    foreach( $users as $user ) {
        echo $user->sumed;
    }
}
add_shortcode('customer_gain', 'get_customer_gain');
```

How can I merge those two query and then get the difference between the two? I'm getting both numbers `A - B = C` (I want `C`) bike minus car.

Comment: You're only going to get one result from each query since you're using an aggregate function (sum) without grouping.  In other words, do you really need to do anything with arrays?

Comment: Similar to tickets... I paid X amount for every tickets then I sold Y tickets with profit...  I would like to know my profit but comparing my actual costs and what I made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
С = array_diff(A, B);
```

Comment: They are asking for a mathematical operation,  not the different values between  the arrays.